# What's the meaning of the word "would" here?

Tags: modal-verbs

> The War Chief believes that this raid upon the unsuspecting prison will strike terror into the hearts of those who **would** dare resist the Horde.

Having been struggling with it, *would* is the most confusing word for me. I know those regular usages of it, but still encountering uncertainties very often.

Does the *would* in the quoted sentence have the meaning of *might*?

Is this the correct understanding?

> If anyone dares resist the Horde, he will be struck terror into his heart.

Comment: As a learner: here "would" is a modal used because the situation is hypothetical or it's a hypothetical "will"!

Comment: You are correct; you could substitute the word "might" in place of "would" and not change the meaning of the sentence.